# Python regex get substring after preceding substring match

Tags: python, regex

Text has no spaces, so I cannot split at all and use indexing on a list of strings.

The pattern I am looking for is:

`check=`

It is followed by a number and encoded querystring items (apache logfile) and is on every line of the file twice.  I want output that gives me just what follows `check=`

For instance, the string in a line looks like:

```
11.249.222.103 - - [15/Aug/2016:13:17:56 -0600] "GET /next2/120005079807?check=37593467%2CCOB&check=37593378%2CUAP&box=match&submit=Next HTTP/1.1" 500 1633 "https://mvt.squaretwofinancial.com/newmed/?button=All&submit=Submit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

And I need to fetch `37593467` and `37593378` in this case.

Comment: `re.findall(r'(?<=check=)\d+', text)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this code.

```
import re

text = '''11.249.222.103 - - [15/Aug/2016:13:17:56 -0600] "GET /next2/120005079807?check=37593467%2CCOB&check=37593378%2CUAP&box=match&submit=Next HTTP/1.1" 500 1633 "https://mvt.squaretwofinancial.com/newmed/?button=All&submit=Submit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"'''


for match in re.findall("check=(\d+)",text):
    print 'Found "%s"' % match
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python demo.py
Found "37593467"
Found "37593378"
```

Couple of URLs for help :

- [Python regex Tester](http://www.pyregex.com/)
- [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: ok, to modify, how do I also search on the text after...i.e. how do I get the match to display the number based on whether it found `%2CCOB` or `%2CUAP`?